# Adding Oracle Spatial Layer using Python Bindings of QGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, oracle-spatial

I want to load a layer from my Oracle Spatial Database using the Python bindings of QGIS. I have tried loading the layer by creating the uri as shown in some previous posts.

I am using the python bindings that were installed by default when I installed the QGIS_Wein 32 bit executable.

I am able to connect to the database by using cx_Oracle cursor, but when I am trying to create a vector layer using the URI , It is not happening.
That layer object always returns false to isValid() function.

Do I have to install anything else apart from the cx_Oracle & QGIS executable to add a layer?

Comment: Have you examined the db logs to see what it says about the failure?

Comment: @Brad Nesom : From where can I see db logs!!

Comment: I don't have oracle now but just googled the answer to your question. which would depend on your version/level/os. But here is how to query the system variable on SE. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197033/where-is-the-oracle-event-log-located. also here is the oracle documentation. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/core.1012/b13995/log.htm

Comment: I have checked the logs there is only entry there related to my python app ; and that is corresponding to the fetching the tables with "SDO_GEOMETRY" column.

Comment: I feel QGIS is not able to talk to the cx_ORacle lib that I have installed; do I have to make any changes in my environment variable regarding that!

Comment: Please use the [edit] button rather than comments to improve your question.